# Issue with implementing the compare function in a priority queue

Tags: c++, huffman-code

So I'm building a huffman compressor/decompressor and I'm having an issue with how the symbols, frequencies, and their corresponding code are printing out. I coded a nodecompare function for the priority queue that will first compare frequencies, then symbols, and as a last resort then the nodeID's (giving priority to the newly created node). Though my output is not what is expected and I can't seem to figure out where exactly the issue in my code is. Please help.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    char symbol;
    int frequency;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    int nodeID;

   Node(char s, int f) : symbol(s), frequency(f), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
};

struct NodeCompare
{
    bool operator()(Node *n1, Node *n2)
    {
        if (n1->frequency == n2->frequency) {
            if (n1->symbol == n2->symbol) {
                return n1->nodeID > n2->nodeID;
            }
            return n1->symbol > n2->symbol;
        }
        else return n1->frequency > n2->frequency;
    }
};

void buildHuffmanTree(priority_queue<Node *, vector<Node *>, NodeCompare> &pq)
{
    static int nodeCounter = 0;

    while (pq.size() > 1)
    {
        Node *left = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        Node *right = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        Node *parent = new Node('$', left->frequency + right->frequency);
        parent->nodeID = ++nodeCounter;
        parent->left = left;
        parent->right = right;
        pq.push(parent);
    }
}

void printCodes(Node *root, string code)
{
    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (root->symbol != '$')
    {
        cout << "Symbol: " << root->symbol << ", Frequency: " << root->frequency << ", Code: " << code << endl;
    }
    printCodes(root->left, code + "0");
    printCodes(root->right, code + "1");
}

int main() {
    string input_file = "input_file.txt";
    //cin >> input_file;

    ifstream infile(input_file);

    vector<Node *> symbols;
    char symbol;
    int frequency;
    priority_queue<Node *, vector<Node *>, NodeCompare> pq;

    string inputline;

    while (getline(infile, inputline)){
        istringstream ss(inputline);
        ss >> std::noskipws >> symbol;
        ss >> std::skipws >> frequency;

        Node *node = new Node(symbol, frequency);
        symbols.push_back(node);
        pq.push(node);
    }

    buildHuffmanTree(pq);
    Node *root = pq.top();
    printCodes(root, "");
}
```

actual output:

```
Symbol: 0, Frequency: 2, Code: 000
Symbol: 2, Frequency: 2, Code: 001
Symbol: C, Frequency: 2, Code: 010
Symbol: S, Frequency: 2, Code: 011
Symbol:  , Frequency: 3, Code: 100
Symbol: R, Frequency: 1, Code: 1010
Symbol: 6, Frequency: 1, Code: 10110
Symbol: G, Frequency: 1, Code: 10111
Symbol: 3, Frequency: 3, Code: 110
Symbol: I, Frequency: 1, Code: 11100
Symbol: N, Frequency: 1, Code: 11101
Symbol: O, Frequency: 1, Code: 11110
Symbol: P, Frequency: 1, Code: 11111
```

expected output:

```
Symbol: 0, Frequency: 2, Code: 000
Symbol: 2, Frequency: 2, Code: 001
Symbol: I, Frequency: 1, Code: 0100
Symbol: N, Frequency: 1, Code: 0101
Symbol: 6, Frequency: 1, Code: 0110
Symbol: G, Frequency: 1, Code: 0111
Symbol: R, Frequency: 1, Code: 1000
Symbol: O, Frequency: 1, Code: 10010
Symbol: P, Frequency: 1, Code: 10011
Symbol:  , Frequency: 3, Code: 101
Symbol: 3, Frequency: 3, Code: 110
Symbol: C, Frequency: 2, Code: 1110
Symbol: S, Frequency: 2, Code: 1111
```

Comment: Unrelated note: I see a `new` and no `delete`s. That's a pretty much guaranteed memory leak.

Comment: `bool operator()(Node *n1, Node *n2)` should be `const` qualified and the pointers should also point at `const` `Node`s: `bool operator()(const Node *n1, const Node *n2) const`

Comment: Pop a breakpoint in `operator()` and step through enough calls to convince yourself that it behaves exactly as expected.

Comment: Recommendation: Finish up the example. Add in the headers and write up a simple `main` function that does exactly enough to demonstrate the problem. No more and no less. Often isolating the problem in the smallest amount of code you can makes the solution obvious. And even if it isn't, you've effectively found the bug, making it much easier to experiment with.

Comment: `bool operator()(Node *n1, Node *n2) { return std::tie(n1->frequency, n1->symbol, n1->nodeID) > std::tie(n2->frequency, n2->symbol, n2->nodeID); }` -- That one line using `std::tie` does the work of all of those cascading `if` statements.

Comment: There is no need to use a "special" byte to identify a leaf. A dollar sign may appear in your input, at which point your code is broken. You can tell it's a leaf by seeing if either of the pointers are `nullptr`. So instead of `if (root->symbol != '$')` use `if (root->left == nullptr)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd normally suggest using `std::tie` for creating comparators, but in this case, I'll settle for two minor changes.

- You need to treat the parent nodes, the `$` symbols, separately. A non-parent node should come after a parent node in the queue given that they have the same frequency.
- You need to swap the priority order of the `nodeID`s.

```cpp
struct NodeCompare {
    bool operator()(const Node *n1, const Node *n2) const {
        if (n1->frequency == n2->frequency) {
            if (n1->symbol == n2->symbol) {
                return n1->nodeID < n2->nodeID;
//                               ^^^ swapped
            }
            if (n1->symbol != '$' && n2->symbol == '$') return true;
// if `n1` is _not_ a parent node but `n2` is, then return true
            return n1->symbol > n2->symbol;
        } else
            return n1->frequency > n2->frequency;
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YY66zq9sb)

---

An easier way would be to use a different "parent" character and instead use one that would be sorted in the correct order naturally. That would be the character with the smallest value.

```cpp
#include <limits>

constexpr char Parent = std::numeric_limits<char>::min(); // -128 probably
```

Then use `Parent` everywhere where you now use `'$'`.

With that, you don't need to treat the parent nodes separately and can use the much easier to implement comparator using `std::tie`:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

struct NodeCompare {
    bool operator()(const Node *n1, const Node *n2) const {
        return std::tie(n1->frequency, n1->symbol, n2->nodeID) >
               std::tie(n2->frequency, n2->symbol, n1->nodeID);
               // note that the ordering of `nodeID` still needs to be swapped
    };
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MGrfhTzfq)

---

If you don't like the idea of having a different ordering rule for `nodeID`, but rather have ...

```cpp
struct NodeCompare {
    bool operator()(const Node *n1, const Node *n2) const {
        return std::tie(n1->frequency, n1->symbol, n1->nodeID) >
               std::tie(n2->frequency, n2->symbol, n2->nodeID);
    };
};
```

... you only need to use a decreasing counter instead of an increasing one:

```cpp
parent->nodeID = --nodeCounter; // was parent->nodeID = ++nodeCounter;
```

Comment: (I left some of my own debugging outputs in the demo - it may be helpful)

Answer (score 1):

There is *nothing wrong* with your actual output. Both the actual output and expected output are optimal Huffman codes. Both code the shown frequencies in a total of 76 bits, which is the sum over the symbols of the frequency times the code length. Because this set of frequencies results in ties when deciding on which of the lowest frequencies to combine next (in fact, many ties), there are different, equally valid choices at those steps that result in different trees and different codes. No matter what choices are made, an optimal code is generated that codes the input in a total of 76 bits, every time.

For that particular set of frequencies, seven 1's, four 2's, and two 3's, there are so many ties that there are 16 topologically distinct trees that can arise, depending on how the choices are made. Here are all of those trees:

[image: 16 trees]

What's more, for each of those trees, each branch can *independently* be made 0 on the left and 1 on the right, *or* 1 on the left and 0 on the right. Every topology has 12 branches (one less than the number of symbols), and so there are 4096 possible assignments of 0's and 1's to the codes for each topology.

In total then, I can generate 65,536 different Huffman codes for that set of frequencies, all of which are valid and all of which are equally optimal. You are showing two of those. There is nothing special about either of them.

There *is* something special about the last two trees shown above, in that they have a depth (longest code length) of four, whereas all of the other trees have depth five. Some might prefer a minimum depth tree, which neither of the codes you showed are. You can resolve ties to get a minimum depth tree by combining the minimum depth leaves and/or subtrees of the same frequency. (Leaves have depth zero.)

In order to to do that, you would keep track of the depth and sort on it when the frequencies are equal. To do that, I would make `symbol` an `int` instead of `char`, and store the depths of subtrees as negative numbers in `symbol`. I.e. -1 for depth one, -2 for depth two, and so on. (Make sure your symbols are always non-negative, so bytes must be 0..255, not -128..127.) Then when the frequencies are equal, prefer the maximum values of `symbol`.

In `struct Node`, have:

```
    int symbol;
```

and add to `struct Node`:

```
    int depth() {
        return left == nullptr ? 0 : -symbol;
    }
```

The new `NodeCompare` is:

```
struct NodeCompare
{
    bool operator()(Node *n1, Node *n2)
    {
        if (n1->frequency != n2->frequency)
            return n1->frequency > n2->frequency;
        else
            return n1->symbol < n2->symbol;
    }
};
```

The depth is updated in `buildHuffmanTree()` using:

```
        Node *parent = new Node(-(max(left->depth(), right->depth()) + 1),
                                left->frequency + right->frequency);
```

For showing the tree, you didn't need the `$` business anyway. Just check one of the pointers:

```
    if (root->left == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Symbol: " << (char)(root->symbol) << ", Frequency: " << root->frequency << ", Code: " << code << endl;
    }
```

Now it will construct a minimum depth, but still optimal tree, which in this case is depth four:

```
Symbol: 0, Frequency: 2, Code: 000
Symbol: O, Frequency: 1, Code: 0010
Symbol: N, Frequency: 1, Code: 0011
Symbol: R, Frequency: 1, Code: 0100
Symbol: P, Frequency: 1, Code: 0101
Symbol: I, Frequency: 1, Code: 0110
Symbol: G, Frequency: 1, Code: 0111
Symbol: 3, Frequency: 3, Code: 100
Symbol:  , Frequency: 3, Code: 101
Symbol: 6, Frequency: 1, Code: 1100
Symbol: S, Frequency: 2, Code: 1101
Symbol: C, Frequency: 2, Code: 1110
Symbol: 2, Frequency: 2, Code: 1111
```

Comment: Seriously cool and easy to follow! Thanks! I adopted the implementation from my answer according to how I understood your answer and got [this](https://godbolt.org/z/r9nchraPn) which has max depth of four. Very nice.